# Predicting probabilities in a logistic regression model

Tags: r

I ran the following logistic regression model with survey data using `svyglm`:

```
model7 <- svyglm(hivcode~I(age)+I(age)*factor(gendercode)+factor(gendercode)+
                 factor(maritalstatuscode)+factor(literacycode)+
                 I(age)*factor(maritalstatuscode)+
                 factor(residencecode),design=shs,family=quasibinomial)
```

I'm trying to obtain predicted probabilities using (something like this):

```
newdata1<-with(new.clean,data.frame(age=mean(age),gendercode=factor(1),
                                    maritalstatuscode=factor(1),
                                    literacycode=factor(1),residencecode=factor(1)))
```

and

```
newdataP <- predeict(model7,newdata=newdata1,type="response").
```

First I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
```

I would also like to know how can one specify specific factor levels such as a 'male' for gender, 'single' for marital status etc in the prediction code.

Comment: Probably a typo in the above code only but it should be `predict` not `predeict`

Answer (score 0):

I would need some more information on the error to comment (a reproducible example works best), but for the gender and marital status, define these classes in your original data `shs` (e.g. `levels(shs$gender) <- c("male", "female")` - order of genders should comfort to your actual order, I suspect it's currently coded as numeric?).

To predict based on gender or marital status, just construct a proper data.frame that should contain all the variables your model has. Function `expand.grid` can work wonders.

```
expand.grid(gender = c("male", "female"), maritalstatus = c("married", "single"), numberofchildren = 0:5)
   gender maritalstatus numberofchildren
1    male       married                0
2  female       married                0
3    male        single                0
4  female        single                0
5    male       married                1
6  female       married                1
7    male        single                1
8  female        single                1
9    male       married                2
10 female       married                2
11   male        single                2
12 female        single                2
13   male       married                3
14 female       married                3
15   male        single                3
16 female        single                3
17   male       married                4
18 female       married                4
19   male        single                4
20 female        single                4
21   male       married                5
22 female       married                5
23   male        single                5
24 female        single                5
```